# Vue - deep nested object access Image on parent

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, object, nested-object

I have 2 V-for to render a nested Object. On 2nd level of my object I have an Image, but I need to render that Image on my first V-for.

```
  <div v-for="(fruit, key) in fruits" :key="key">
        <div>
            <img :src="IWantRenderImageHereFrom2ndVfor" alt="" />
            <h1>{{ fruit }}</h1>
        </div>

        <div v-for="(piece, key) in fruit" :key="key">
            <h2>{{ key }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's how my object is structured

```
   const fruits = {
    apple: {
        green: {
            image: image1,
            name: "green"
        },
        yellow: {
            image: image1,
            name: "yellow"
        }
    },
    mango: {
        red: {
            image: image2,
            name: "red"
        },
        pink: {
            image: image2,
            name: "pink"
        }
    }
};
```

every 2nd level object will have same image that I want to render on 1st level object.
I already tried to grab the image and create a new key on 1st level but then when looping to render the 2nd level it throw me an error

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Tony basically because of the loop of 2nd level object has keys that Image doesnt have, for example mango.red.name It renders, but mango.image.name doesnt exist. I dont know if I can skip the image property when loop
Edit: I've updated the object with a name key to be easier to understand

Comment: Each grandchild of `fruits` has an `image` key, so which one would you want for the child?

Comment: @tony19 each grandchild will have same images, so I just want grab one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is not unique to the color objects, it doesn't make sense to store it there, and the repetition is a sign that it's not right.  You could use a structure like this instead, where the image is a property of the 1st level:

```js
const fruits = {
    apple: {
        image: "https://via.placeholder.com/200/333333",
        colors: ['green', 'yellow']
    },
    mango: {
        image: "https://via.placeholder.com/200/999999",
        colors: ['red', 'pink']
    },
};
```

You can replace the color objects with a simple array.  The template becomes:

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(fruit, key) in fruits" :key="key">
    <div>
      <img :src="fruit.image" alt="" />
      <h1>{{ key }}</h1>
    </div>

    <div v-for="color in fruit.colors" :key="color">
      <h2>{{ color }}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a demo:

```js
const fruits = {
    apple: {
        image: "https://via.placeholder.com/200/333333",
        colors: ['green', 'yellow']
    },
    mango: {
        image: "https://via.placeholder.com/200/999999/FFFFFF",
        colors: ['red', 'pink']
    },
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      fruits
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(fruit, key) in fruits" :key="key">
    <div>
      <img :src="fruit.image" alt="" />
      <h1>{{ key }}</h1>
    </div>

    <div v-for="color in fruit.colors" :key="color">
      <h2>{{ color }}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```